# Hats black in IE 11

Tags: bug, status-completed, winter-bash

There seems to be a bug in IE that causes many of the hats to just display completely black in IE 11 on Windows 10:

[image]

Just for reference, these are the same hats shown in Google Chrome on the same PC:

[image]

Comment: It seems IE11 is not comphatible with Winter Bash.

Comment: I know hackers wear black hats, but I didn't think hackers used IE 11....

Comment: And before anyone ask, [IE 11 is supported by SE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/71208/213575)

Comment: This is fine. You just found 5 new black secret hats...

Comment: This is a bug with IE11 that they need to fix. They're ignoring the entire `<style>` block of the SVG image which is causing the colors not to be applied to the appropriate sections. Weird that some of the colors work and others don't. All the images are built the exact same way.

Comment: @animuson will SE poke at IE team?

Comment: @animuson: [Good luck getting them to fix anything in IE11 but security issues anymore.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35184048/what-is-after-internet-explorer-11-on-windows-7-how-well-will-es2016-be-support/35184087#35184087)

Comment: This bug only occurs with dataURI svgs, if we use a blobURI everything is fine, so one could make a user-script like var `hats = document.querySelectorAll('img'); Array.prototype.forEach.call(hats, function(img){ var src = img.src; if(src.indexOf('data:')!==0){ return; } var markup = decodeURIComponent(src.substr(src.indexOf(',')+1, src.length)); img.src = URL.createObjectURL( new Blob([markup], {type: 'image/svg+xml'})); });`. Note that I wasn't able to make a selector like `'.hats img[src^=data], [id*=hat] img[src^=data]'` to work on IE11, but I don't really know this UA.

Comment: Sometimes I wonder if IE development was some sort of "fun" project at MS

Comment: @I Love CSS: Yeah, I'm sure they had nothing better to do than to create their own browser when everyone was well and happy with Netscape Navigator, let alone maintain it for the next 20 years before finally laying it to rest... only to create *another* one.

Comment: The real issue is that you're using IE in the first place.

Comment: In Edge they work fine, which is the windows 10 default browser, Internet explorer is only there to support older websites still ;)

Comment: @Icepickle Only on Win10.

Comment: @phk Yeah, true, but the ts also mentioned he is using windows 10

Comment: Doesn't this belong on meta.stackexchange?

Comment: @Kaiido IE does have issues with large data-URI values. Might be what's happening? "Data URIs cannot be larger than 32,768 characters." - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc848897.aspx

Comment: @TiesonT. Nope they do allow larger dataURI for media elements :-) This seems to be a bug only occuring in win10's version of IE11 aniway, it works on my win8 VM's.

Comment: @devRicher Bug reports can be posted on both Meta.SO and Meta.SE.

Comment: This is interesting: it should be migrated to SO.

Comment: IE is the new black

Comment: You know, sometimes I wonder why MS carried IE on for ~20-21 years before dropping support, and what shocks me more than the (ridiculous) amount of support MS gave a (failing) project like IE, is the fact that they created *yet another* (about to fail) project based off IE's old source code (Edge).

Comment: @Kaiido: This would not be the only issue specific to IE11 on Windows 10. But the issues I've found were at least *fixable*, unlike one with Google Chrome that I haven't been able to fix without completely neutering the feature resulting in an IE8-like experience...

Comment: @Mango: The only alternative is bundling a third-party browser with Windows. If something goes wrong, it's not on the browser vendor, it's on Microsoft. Would you be willing to take responsibility for something you have no direct control over? (In b4 "Microsoft doesn't even take responsibility for their own bugs anyway.")

Comment: @BoltClock What you're saying makes perfect sense and no I would not take responsibility for such a thing, but at the same time I would be able to understand when to move on, I think that Microsoft did not understand this until it was far too late and they had already lost their majority in the market.

Comment: @Mango: I agree. But then again, it's not like the present WebKit/Blink monoculture is much better ;)

Comment: @BoltClock, I'm not sure what I did say that triggered this comment, but I definitely found bugs in IE (not only in 11) that could not be fixed in any way... I'm not a big Webkit fan either, (and in my day work I even often consider chrome the new IE) but they've got the merit to at least have an open bug report system, so for your unsolvable bug, [maybe try to file something](http://chromiumbugs.appspot.com/) ;-) or even post a question on main, some may have an hackish way to workaround.

Answer (score 2):

This was fixed back in 2017 WinterBash and later by balpha, [answer here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/304366/is-winterbash-2017-disabled-for-internet-explorer-users/304368#304368).