# Do we need a [status-obsolete] tag?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, tags

I just did a search on bugs [which have no status-* tag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5bbug%5d%20closed%3ano%20-%5bstatus-*%5d).

[One of the higher voted bugs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/340293/hats-black-in-ie-11) is about [winterbash](/questions/tagged/winterbash), which is obviously obsolete. Not speaking about a feature, [which was sunsetted](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354217/sunsetting-documentation).

Does it make to sence to introduce a [status-obsolete](/questions/tagged/status-obsolete) Tag for such cases?

Answer (score 2):

Nah, [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined) works just fine. [It's used for old Documentation stuff, in fact.](/q/344049/6388243)

Answer (score 1):

Who's to say that when Winterbash rolls around again that some poor Internet Explorer 11 user will *still* experience this issue?

I don't see any benefit in this sort of tag, since it won't be any different than [status-norepro](/questions/tagged/status-norepro) or [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined).

Comment: I think they meant a specific hat.

Comment: Arg, you are right. Winterbash was a bad example. But what's about Documentation for example? I can see some semantic differences to norepro.

Comment: @ChristianGollhardt:  Yes, I was having a bit of a mental lapse over "declined" there.  I've revised my answer.

Comment: @ChristianGollhardt Alternatively, just vote to close the question as "no reproducible" instead of waiting for the status tag.