# Why isn't Internet Explorer showing the Winter Bash icon or hats?

Tags: bug, internet-explorer, winter-bash-2017

The Winter Bash icon is shown in Edge, but not in Internet Explorer.

#### Microsoft Edge 40.15063.674.0

[image]

#### IE 11.726.15063.0

[image]

Why doesn't IE show the icon?

Comment: http://shouldiblamecaching.com/

Comment: @Cerbrus, Are you saying that edge has the right behavior? Because i just try with a fresh intal of chrome with the same result as IE..

Comment: Hm, usually, caching is the culprit, but after checking it again, here, I can actually reproduce the issue...

Comment: I'd say you need a browser with an extra Edge.

Comment: When only Edge give the expected result there is something wrong..

Comment: I can't tell if this is a circlejerk disguised as a bug report, or if this is a legitimate bug report because someone legitimately thinks that Edge displaying the Winter Bash icon *is a bug*.

Comment: @BoltClock, At the time of testing every browser (IE, FF, Chrome, Opera) Failed to load the icon. So I thought it was an Edge issue.. I also di'dt knew about IE not beeing supported as it was on

Comment: Seems to be just you. All browsers other than IE display the icon just fine for me.

Comment: I have screen shoot... It seems to be delay related. Or something went wrong in my infra some where. But it's 100% not a bug from SO side base on the information comment on the previously existing  answer provide

Comment: Internet Explorer is not compatible with Winter Bash.

Comment: @CassioMazzochiMolin Sounds like IE did something right for a change!

Comment: @TylerH, I guess it's duplicate now ..

Comment: @DragandDrop Yes, looks like it was from the get go.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hats black in IE 11](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/340293/hats-black-in-ie-11)

Comment: @TylerH, in fact it was not. All Browser had the IE  only issue except Edge. But the Vm and the screen shoot are lost . and i didnt make my post a spam of image I just took the 2 most revelant the good Edge and his brother IE.

Comment: @DragandDrop Well the original issue was caching, but once caching was ruled out the issue was that IE is old and other browsers work fine. This has been asked on MSE this year and on MSO last year for Winterbash 2016 and the reason hasn't changed, so it's a duplicate.

Answer (score 29):

[Winter Bash is disabled in Internet Explorer.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/304366/is-winterbash-2017-disabled-for-internet-explorer-users)

This is due to a [compatibility issue](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/340293/hats-black-in-ie-11). The hats appear black in Internet Explorer, so Stack Exchange decided to disable it there. This is why you see it in Edge properly.

Comment: And if I want black hats?

Comment: @James_Parsons Then use a modern browser that supports an addon like Stylish and replace all hat SVGs with a black box.

Comment: Black hats on Stack Overflow, run away!